# Progressive disclosure of navigation in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this layout that has a navigation at the top, followed by an image. The hero image has a negative top margin in order for the transparency thing on the nav work.

```
+----------------------------------------+
| a.logo Home Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 Cat4 Cat5   |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                        |
| Huge hero image here                   |
|                                        |
+----------------------------------------+
```

`a.logo` is the branding of the site, with an image inside it. Items from `home` to `cat5` (actually there are more categories there, but you get the idea) are in an `<ul>` with inline-blocked `<li>`. The problem is that when the screen resizes, the clipped `<li>` items merely go down the drain (as with Fig.2.) I want it to just be clipped, as with Fig. 3.

Fig.2:

```
+----------------------------------+
| a.logo Home Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 Cat4  |
|                  Cat5            |
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
| Huge hero image here             |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

Fig. 3:

```
+----------------------------------+
| a.logo Home Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 Cat4  |
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
| Huge hero image here             |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

Here's a semi-actual code (real content are withheld):

```
<div id="nameplate" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="nav" class="twelvecol last">
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="The Logo"></a></a>
            <ul id="nav_ul">
                <li><a href="">Cat 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cat 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cat 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cat 4</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Cat 5</a>
                    <ul class="social-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">YouTube</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">RSS Feed</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Styling stuff:

```
.container#nameplate { margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0; position: relative; text-align: center; z-index: 3; }
.container#nameplate #nav .logo, .container#nameplate #nav > ul { display: inline; vertical-align: middle; }
.container#nameplate #nav .logo { display: inline-block; }
.container#nameplate #nav > ul { height: 32px; overflow: hidden; }
.container#nameplate #nav li { font: 300 1.25em 'Oswald', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; display: inline-block; line-height: 2.1em; list-style: none; margin-right: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; vertical-align: middle }
.container#nameplate #nav li a { color: #ccc; padding: 3px; }
.container#nameplate #nav li a:hover { color: #fbfbfb; text-decoration: none; }
.container#nameplate #nav ul.social-dropdown { position: absolute; }
.container#nameplate #nav ul.social-dropdown li { display: block; font-size: 80%; text-align: left; }
```

I've tried `overflow: hidden` on it, plus a fixed height on `div#nameplate`, but it would cut off the dropdown menu that is expected to show up on the last `<li>` item.

Any ideas on how to execute this responsive thing without that dropdown getting cut off?

Comment: Surely it doesn't make sense to start simply hiding NAV items from users on a smaller screen? Usual practice would be to start stacking the logo and NAV items on top of each other rather than displaying them horizontally.

Comment: Have you tried setting a width on the `<ul>` element?

Comment: @BillyMoat, setting the `ul#nav` to `display:inline-block` stacks it along with the logo, but at the expense of an extra margin at the top. My hypothesis is that it's due to the negative margin caused by the positioning of the hero image _under_ the nav.

@Raffael, Setting a width on `<ul>` clips the entirety of the nav on bigger screens where those extra items should appear. `min-width` doesn't help either.

Comment: Maybe remove the negative margin on the hero on smaller screens too then?

Comment: @BillyMoat Removing the negative margin creates a blank space at the top of the hero image, so it doesn't 'bleed' at the back of the nav. The nav should appear superimposed on the image.

Comment: It may be that in order to have the site working well on small screen devices you'll have to rethink the layout at that level. On large screen your original design may work well but on small screens not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Edit2: [Here's an example of the below idea on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdeFF/).

Edit: Define a width for your `.logo`, and set `#nav` to `position: relative` (ie. the parent `div` of your navigation list). Set `position: absolute` on your `#nav ul`, and place it `left: XXpx; right: 0;` where "XX" is equal to the width of your logo and any extra space you wish to place between it and the navigation.

---

`display: block` on the ul will allow it hide the overflow. That will have a knock on effect on your layout, but you'll just need to define a width to reign it in.

Comment: Setting a permanent width on the `<ul>` totally hides the items even on larger screens (or browser windows), when that should only be 'clipped' on smaller browser widths. `min-width` doesn't help; and I presume `max-width` won't, either.